# Is there any way to add to a column name in R?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and need a bit of help. Basically, I have microarray data in a data frame and would like to append to the column name. Columns are named: A, B, C, etc.

> [user] > names(first.df)
>
> [1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

Another data frame identifies each factor (A, B, C, etc.) as "good" or "bad"

> [user] > second.df
>
> [1]
> A     good
>
> B     bad
>
> C     bad
>
> D     good

Is there any way to add the "good"/"bad" to the column header of the first data frame?

> [user] > names(first.df)
>
> [1]  "A-good"  "B-bad"   "C-bad"   "D-good"

I've tried isolating names to their own data frame (e.g. names(first.df) <- c(names(first.df), second.df[,2]) and merging with no luck. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do it. Here's a quick way:

```
  paste(names(first.df), second.df, sep="-")
```

Comment: @SteveHwang, then please consider voting up and accepting the answer, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: @flodel, I appreciate the link. I will do that from now on. Thanks.